In D3D12 why RTV and DSV descriptors used as a CPU descriptor?
In D3D12, for common descriptors (e.g., GPU-visible descriptors such as CBV/UAV)，we generally
//often use like this
SetDescriptorHeaps(heap);
GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();

But this is not the case for RTV and DSV, we are using OMSetRenderTargets，this method uses D3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE。
It makes me feel very confused.It seems to me that the descriptor is used to interpret a piece of memory in the GPU, so why do you need to pass CPU_DESCRIPTOR to the GPU?Why can't RTV and DSV be passed around for use like other descriptors?

The SetDescriptorHeaps method sets the current 'texture' and 'sampler' heaps for active use. There is no need to do this for Render Target Views or Depth Stencil Views because they are 'made active' by calling OMSetRenderTargets.
In general, the total number of RTVs and DSVs is going to be much smaller than the number of CBVs, SRVs, and UAVs used in a program.
